# allocating oversized memory - pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I don't truly understand the interest of writing this

```
   struct iphdr *ip;
   struct icmphdr *icmp;
   char *packet;
   packet = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr));
   ip = (struct iphdr *)packet;
```

Why taking `packet` as a `char`, and, suppose so why not writing `packet = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));` or simplier `ip = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));` ?

Comment: Does it continue `icmp = (struct icmphdr*)(packet + sizeof (struct iphdr));`? I guess the author wants the structs next to each other for locality.

Comment: ok thanks that's it interesting indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per wikipedia, The icmp header starts immediately after IP header, so the implementor would have thought of allocating one chunk of memory together and making it point to packet.

You can check your code further to find how packet is being used further. The whole content of packet may be getting prepended to some data from above layer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code is allocating an IP packet with an ICMP packet embedded as the IP payload. That's why the size of the `malloc()` is large enough to hold both structures.

The reason it is done like this is so that you get one chunk of *contiguous* memory to represent the packet. If you allocated the `iphdr` and `icmphdr` separately they would most likely be at 2 disjoint portions of memory and thus couldn't be passed to `sendto()`.

Note, because the code is defining the IP header `IP_HDRINCL` socket option must be enabled on the socket so that the socket layer doesn't automatically generate an IP header.

Think of `packet` as just a big buffer. Then `*ip` and `*icmp` are set to point to the right places in that buffer so that it can be initialised using the structs rather than having to do raw byte copies into the struct.